# nested for loop in javascript knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, linq.js

I have two observable arrays:

```
var viewModel = {
    PositionTypes: ko.observableArray([]),
    Users: ko.observableArray([])
}
```

**POSITION ViewModel**

```
var positionViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.PositionName = ko.observable(data.PositionName);
        _self.PositionRank = ko.observable(data.PositionRank);
        _self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
    }

    positionViewModel.AddPositions = function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            positionViewModel.PushPosition(value);
        });
    };

    positionViewModel.PushPosition = function (postion) {
        viewModel.PositionTypes.push(new positionViewModel(position));
    };
```

**USER ViewModel**

```
    // the ViewModel for a single User
    var userViewModel = function (data) {
        var _self = this;
        _self.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
        _self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        _self.Email = ko.observable(data.Email);
        _self.ContentRole = ko.observable(data.ContentRole);
    };

    userViewModel.AddUsers = function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            userViewModel.PushUser(value);
        });
    };


    userViewModel.PushUser = function (user) {
        viewModel.Users.push(new userViewModel(user));
    };
```

How can i using linq.js so that i could loop through every position so i could get all the users for each position?

```
foreach( each position in positions)
{
    foreach(each user in users)
    { list of users for the position}
}
```

Comment: What is the link between an user and a position ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [ko.utils.arrayForEach](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) as follow :

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.PositionTypes(), function(position){    
     var usersInPosition = ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.Users(), function(user){
          return user.ContentRole() == position.ContentRole();
     });
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(usersInPosition, function(user){        

    });
});
```

**[See doc](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)**

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks i will try it out. Will this structure affect the performance overall or not?

Comment: No, but if the ID or the Name properties are not changed on the client side, you could "replace" these observables by regular properties.

Comment: Rather than using `arrayForEach()` here, I think it would be more appropriate to use `arrayMap()` instead.

Comment: What if i wanted to use linq like: `linq.From(viewModel.PositionTypes) ....` i would like to use linq.js and passing in a string

Answer (score 0):

Using linq.js, you can perform a join on the columns you want to compare.

Assuming you are joining between the `ContentRole`s:

```
var query = Enumerable.From(viewModel.PositionTypes())
    .GroupJoin(viewModel.Users(),
        "$.ContentRole()",  // position selector
        "$.ContentRole()",  // user selector
        "{ Position: $, Users: $$.ToArray() }")
    .ToArray();
```

---

So I think you want to create an object that contains a mapping of all the positions and user names.  You can create such an object using the `Aggregate()` function to collect all the results into a single object.

```
var userPositions = Enumerable.From(this.PositionTypes())
    .GroupJoin(this.Users(),
        "$.ContentRole()",  // position selector
        "$.ContentRole()",  // user selector
        "{ Position: $, Users: $$ }") // group all users per position
    .Aggregate(
        {}, // start with an empty object
        function (userPositions, x) {
            var positionName = x.Position.PositionName(),
                userNames = x.Users.Select("$.Name()").ToArray();

            // add the new property
            userPositions[positionName] = userNames;
            return userPositions;
        }
    );
```

Comment: and in my view i would data-bind on the query to display the infor?

Comment: You can certainly do that. Though you haven't shown us your view or how you intended to use the results so I just gave a generic example of what you can do in your query.  This query groups all users by position.

Comment: I wanted to use linq.js and pass in a string so that the outer loop would be positions and then selecting users for each position grouping each user with its position

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. If you're saying that you want to group all users by a certain position, the query above as I've shown should do it for you. If you're having a hard time trying to describe what you're saying, it would help if you gave an example of some input data and an example of your expected output data.

Comment: So i have a list of positions: (boss, supervisor, worker) and i have a list of users(adam, matt, tim, tom, john). I want to write a linq like query in javascript something like this: `linq.From(viewModel.PositionTypes).ForEach(users in viewModel.Users.where(x=>x.ContentRole == viewModel.PositionTypes.ContentRole) //return info` and the result will be like: `Boss: John; Supervisor: matt, tim; Workers: adam, tim`

Comment: I went ahead and applied your update but when i debug in the console `console.log(userPositions)` it returns empty?

Comment: I created a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/AUP9X/.  See if that helps you out.